# How can I display a dialog box on Win-7 or win-10 for 5 seconds, from the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd.exe, vbscript

While searching here, I came across this code on another question:

```
(echo MsgBox "Line 1" ^& vbCrLf ^& "Line 2",262192, "Title")> File.vbs
start File.vbs
```

It worked for me. My problem is, it is expecting user to click "OK" button to close. I want it to auto-close after 5 or 10 (or any predetermined number of) seconds.

I searched for "vbs" "close window" and few variations but ended up with nothing. Is there a way I can accomplish this purpose of mine ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252237/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-messagebox-to-automatically-dismiss-after-a-set-interval

Comment: @LesFerch : a little more convoluted than a one or two liner I was looking for but definitely workable solution. Since I am trying to incorporate this into a cmd batch file, I will have to be extra careful with the syntax and what-not.

Comment: Just a bit of friendly advice... I see these mashups of batch files and VBScript all too often. It just makes your scripting tasks unnecessarily difficult. I encourage you to write your entire script in VBScript or PowerShell. The end result will be much cleaner and easier to debug.

Comment: @LesFerch Thanks for the advice but my batch script is actually a very convoluted set of batch files which I wouldn't dare to modify. They are working just okay, writing to different log files. I am just looking for a way to consolidate crucial info out of the logs and present them to the watcher and update this info every 30 seconds or so.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that:

1. You aren't interested in knowing if the window timed out
2. You aren't interested in knowing what button the user clicked on
3. You don't mind writing out a temporary VBScript file to generate the popup (and then removing it after)

then use the following:

```
echo WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Popup "Line 1" ^& vbCrLf ^& "Line 2", 10, "Title", 262192 > %temp%\File.vbs
wscript %temp%\File.vbs
del /f %temp%\File.vbs
```

This will cause a pop-up to appear which has two lines of content ("Line 1" followed by "Line 2"), the title "Title", an exclamation icon, an OK button and a timeout of 10 seconds.

Further details on how to configure this window can be found in the documentation for the [Popup](https://ss64.com/vb/popup.html) command.

It’s worth noting that you can achieve an exclamation mark and an “OK” button with `48` instead of  `262192` (which, technically, isn’t a valid numerical option).

Answer (score 0):

Create a .vbs script that invokes the Windows Script Host popup() method.
That method has a parameter that determines how long the popup message window is shown. Then invoke your script from the command line with "wscript your_script.vbs".

FYI, there are abundant reports of popup() method timing being erratic, and even failing to timeout at all, especially with larger timeout values.